# Appending a secret (pepper) to Argon2 password hashes

Tags: passwords, hash, salt, argon2, pepper

I've read quite a bit of the StackExchange and HackerNews debates on the user of "peppers" in password hash security. There are a number of different implementations of the idea of a pepper, ranging from an additional hardcoded salt in the code `hash(password, pepper, salt)`, to encrypting each password hash separately, in which case the secret key is the pepper.

In the case of one of the middle ground approaches, a shared and secret pepper is included via `hash(hmac(password, pepper),salt)`. This is necessary primarily because of many hashing algorithm's reliance on the Merkle–Damgård construction which is vulnerable to length extension attacks.

However, Argon2 is not based on a Merkle–Damgård construction and therefore this attack would not apply. In using Argon2, can the naive approach of `argon2(password, pepper, salt)` be used?

Additionally, the Argon2 specification Introduction seems to indicate that using HMACs, peppers, or secret keys at all is unnecessary. Is Argon2ID with  strong memory, threads, and time costs enough on its own?

Comment: Read the length [extension attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3979/18298).  It is not a collision attack.

Comment: @kelalaka So HMAC is overkill? Just hash(password + salt + pepper) should be enough?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Argon2 actually allows a pepper [in the algorithm itself](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2#library), called the `secret`. This would be the ideal way to use a pepper, unfortunately most language bindings I've looked at don't expose this parameter (of the [bindings](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2#bindings) listed on GitHub only 2 of them specifically mention supporting keyed hashing).

If the `secret` parameter can't be used, `argon2(hmac(pepper, password))` is a reasonable alternative. `argon2` can be applied outside `hmac` for simplicity, as the way it's generally used it'll give you an output that includes an encoding of the salt and options used. Using `hmac` outside `argon2` should be comparable for security, but then you'd need to keep track of the Argon2 parameters yourself.

---

As for the spec seeming to indicate that a pepper isn't necessary, I assume you're referring to this:

> A trivial solution for password hashing is a keyed hash function such as
>   HMAC. If the protocol designer prefers hashing without secret keys to avoid all the problems with key generation, storage, and update, then he has few alternatives: the generic mode PBKDF2, the Blowfish-based bcrypt, and
>   scrypt.

The way I read it, what that's saying is that a keyed hash is actually the *best* way to hash passwords, so long as you protect the key *really well* (such as using an HSM). The problem is, protecting the key is difficult (HSMs cost money, supporting a pepper with an HSM takes development time), so slow hashes like scrypt, bcrypt, and Argon2 are used instead.

What it's *not* saying is that using a keyed hash *in addition to* Argon2 is a bad idea. Even if you can't protect the key with an HSM, it can still be worthwhile if it's better protected than the password hashes. The worst passwords will always be cracked no matter how high you set the cost (and your users' patience gives you a low upper limit); a pepper can prevent that.

Comment: Just in case, https://docs.rs/rust-argon2/0.8.1/argon2/struct.Config.html  implements the `secret`

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Strike this entire comment. My approach isn't wrong, per se, but argon2 already offers a `secret` parameter. Just use this.

The simplest approach to this—and the one on the strongest cryptographic footing—is (simplistically) `HMAC(key, argon2(password))`. This also still allows the expensive argon2 calculation to be performed client-side for server-relief situations.

Comment: Is the assumption here that there will be one key or many?

Comment: And shouldn't I put the HMAC "inside" of the Argon hash instead of vice versa?

Comment: Re: one key or many, it depends on your threat model but it also doesn't really matter. The primary point is that an attacker with your password database would also need your secret, which should be stored elsewhere. There are also reasons you might want to use multiple keys, but unless you know a specific reason why you would want this, you shouldn't bother with the additional complexity.

Comment: Re: inside or outside, inside prevents server relief, since `argon2(HMAC(key, password))` requires the password to be HMAC'd server-side first. With `HMAC(key, argon2(password))`, a client can compute `argon2(password)` first before sending to the server. This approach also has the secondary advantage of ensuring that the server never actually sees the user's raw password, so there's no chance of it hitting a log file.

Comment: But lastly, `argon2` *already provides* a `secret` parameter. Really, really, really just use this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not supported natively in my language. Adjacently, does Argon explain how they use the optional secret in computing the hash? I couldn't find that anywhere.

Comment: @Prime [It looks like](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/blob/e4ca309b044fdc6ec547a3e1a106b4bfd06563b4/src/core.c#L592) it gets hashed with Blake2b in the same way [the salt does](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/blob/e4ca309b044fdc6ec547a3e1a106b4bfd06563b4/src/core.c#L584).

Comment: What is the library you're using that doesn't support this?

Comment: PHP7.3's native support.